# Import orders from excel file in woocommerce

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

> Create woocommerce order by Uploading Excel file

We have some orders from our customer that they are ordered by directly calling to us . So we have save their details in excel file with every details (customer name address etc to product name , product id , variation id , discount ,coupon details etc ).

We know how to upload data to database through excel by `php` code .

for a sample example

```
<form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$c = 0;

while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
{
    $name = $filesop[0];
    $email = $filesop[1];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO order (name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')");
}

    if($sql){
        echo "Correctly uploaded";
    }else{
        echo "it's not working";
    }

}
```

And we know how to fetch each and every details of product .

But please help to integrate with woocommerce . Since we noticed that each order is saved in `wp_posts` , with `post_type='shop_order'`, and order status as a taxonomy named `shop_order_status` , customer details of order is save as `post_meta` field ets and we know how to use each class in woocommerce for retrieving data for example `WC_Order`,`WC_Order_Item_Meta`.

Please help to complete this . If any one can explain the basic table structure of woocommerce for inserting query through sql, it is also helpful.

Thank you .

> Note :  We need to create sql query  . We don't need to create
>   customer and customer meta table entries , because in this order the
>   customer who place this order is our default company customer service
>   account . So no need to think about customer and customer meta table .
>   The real customer information is added into order meta fields like
>   _billing_phone,_billing_email, _shipping_address_1 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orders are a custom post and are located first in `wp_posts` table with a `'post_type'` like `'shop_order'`.

For each `post_id` (in `wp_posts` table ID) you can retrieve all orders details in `wp_postmeta` table.
This orders have also a relations with `wp_woocommerce_order_items`and `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` where they store additional details related to bought products, quantity, amounts, VAT...

This orders are related also to `wp_users` (as `'customer'`) and `wp_usermeta` tables. You can retrieve the customer ID in `wp_postmeta` table with `meta_key` as `_customer_user`.

Making sql query is going to be complicated, because you need first to create the user (wp_users and wp_usermeta tables).
Then a complex query to populate at the same time 4 tables related to orders.

> **--(update)-- RETRIEVING ORDERS DATA**
>
> **Table wp_posts:**
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE 'post_type' LIKE 'shop_order'
> ```
>
> **Table wp_postmeta:**
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'post_id' = xxxx
> ```
>
> *(xxxx is the id of an order that you can find in wp_posts table)*
>
> **Table wp_woocommerce_order_items:**
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM 'wp_woocommerce_order_items' WHERE 'order_id' = xxxx
> ```
>
> *(xxxx is the id of an order that you can find in wp_posts table)*
>
> **Table wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta:**
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM 'wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta' WHERE 'order_item_id' = yyyy
> ```
>
> *(yyyy is the order_item_id of an order_id that you can find in wp_woocommerce_order_items)*

Comment: Really thank you friend . We need to create sql query friend . We don't need to create customer and customer meta table entries , because in this order the customer who place this order is our default company customer service account . So no need to think about customer and customer meta table . The real customer information is added into order meta fields like _billing_phone,_billing_email, _shipping_address_1 etc

Comment: and payment type will be cash on delivery .And we already have wp_users ,and wp_user_meta for this entries

Comment: Actually what is order reference _order_key  ? this is for to find previous order ? what is order_key real purpose ? Finds an Order ID based on an order key..

Comment: what happen if no orderkey is saved ? for this order we are not using paypal . they all are cash on delivery .

Comment: you are right you dont need this… is for payment gateways sync… At this point I can't help you anymore, because importing csv (or excel) orders that populates database, is a real development job… I will delete my answer…

Comment: No please . It is really useful to other one . to we also

Comment: can you please give the correct table structure and fields for orders . Please don't delete this answer . When i have 15 reputation i will be upvote .

Comment: sorry . we will look  this .

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191730/how-to-limit-post-in-wp-query

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this might be helful to you by doing some customizations in plugin.

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-csvimport/
```

Comment: Good one friend . :) . But it is a plugin . We need just an example for order import , not product .But still it is good , because it will help to understand the working of products