# Limit posts on a WP_Query and in WooCommerce product query

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, product

In Woocommerce, I need to limit post with a `wp_query`.

I know how to limit post in [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_limits)

For example if this page id is 20, I am running the query:

```
function wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits( $limit, $query ) {

    if ( get_the_ID()==20 ) {
        return 'LIMIT 0, 12';
    }

    return $limit;
}


add_filter( 'post_limits', 'wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits', 10, 2 );
```

But I need to set the limt as 25 to 35.

How to do this?

Even if I am placing return `'LIMIT 25, 35';` it is still showing first 35 products, not the posts between 25 to 35.

That query is like: `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15`

Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at this https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination you need to use both offset and pagination and posts per page etc etc...

Comment: i see this 'showposts'          =>2000, 'post_status'   => 'publish',
'offset'            =>11  . but it is not working . i see this . i can change offset 10 , it is pagination number and showpost showing how many post is showing . But i don't know why it is not working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is… *taratata!!!!* :

```
function wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits( $limit, $query ) {
    if ( get_the_ID()==20 ) {
        return 'LIMIT 25, 10'; 
    }
    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits', 10, 2 );
```

Because in `'LIMIT 25, 10';`, here `25` is the offset  and `10` the number of posts to display. So that way it will display 10 products beginning with the product 26…

See this thread: [Whats the difference between post_limits and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191160/whats-the-difference-between-post-limits-and-pre-get-posts)

Comment: Thank you friend :) . I will check this .