# Limit displayed products on Woocommerce product category archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, product

I have a shop with over 30,000 products per category & I want to limit products show on each category by 1000 only For faster load. The rest of product can only find by search.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

you have to put this code into functions.php file

```
function product_pagination_by_category() {
    if( is_product_category() )
        $limit = 10;

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'product_pagination_by_category');
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.

but it is code for display 100 product per page. As I wanted is only show 10 products per page & a total of 1000 products per category = 100 product pages to be show.

Comment: so for that you can use $limit = 10 for 10 products per page.

Comment: So how can I limit product pages showing for each category? like only show 100 pages?

Comment: @PaOp you mean lazy load?

Comment: can you please add your code into question? so i can analyze it and can help you.@PaOp

Answer (score 2):

If you  don't want to do custom code then user plugin called Load More Products for WooCommerce.

Load products from next page via AJAX with infinite scrolling or load more products button

**FEATURES:**

✅ Infinite Scroll for WooCommerce Products

✅ Load More Products Button or AJAX pagination

✅ Custom button text

✅ JavaScript hooks for custom code

check URL : https://wordpress.org/plugins/load-more-products-for-woocommerce/

If you want to go for code then you can check following link. This is already answered:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/235874/87704

Answer (score 2):

You can use `post_limits` hook to limit total displayed products on product category archive pages:

```
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'product_category_archives_limit', 10, 2 );
function product_category_archives_limit( $limit, $query ) {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $limit = 'LIMIT 1000';
    }
    return $limit;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Limit posts on a WP_Query and in WooCommerce product query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191730/limit-posts-on-a-wp-query-and-in-woocommerce-product-query/37200221#37200221)

Comment: Hey there Loic. I've used your code and it limits the products successfully. But there is no pagination appearing so you can jump to next batch. How can I add numbered pagination to this code? Can you help? Thanks!